# Type Error while using for loop in list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, json, list, parsing, dictionary

I'm getting an error while using that structure on Python 3.6 while parsing data from a json file:

```
for topic in data:
    cqas = [{'context':      paragraph['context'],
            'id':           qa['id'],
            'question':     qa['question'],
            'answer':       qa['answers'][0]['text'],
            'answer_start': qa['answers'][0]['answer_start'],
            'answer_end':   qa['answers'][0]['answer_start'] + \
                            len(qa['answers'][0]['text']) - 1,
            'topic':        topic['title'] }
            for paragraph in topic['paragraphs']
            for qa in paragraph['qas']]
```

I couldn't find a documentation about using for loops in list of dicts as mentioned above. I want to learn it because I'm also getting an error message when using that structure:

[image]

Dataset: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YerevaNN/R-NET-in-Keras/master/data/dev-v1.1.json

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? "Using for loop in list of dicts" isn't really a helpful description. Are you trying to loop through a list of dicts and do something on each dict? The code you posted doesn't really make much sense and doesn't show what your goal is.

Comment: this is a list comprehension

Comment: To add to what @Zinki said: an example input and output would be brilliant.

Comment: can you also poste the error message ?

Comment: @Zinki I am trying to use Stanford University's SQuAD Dataset to make a Question-Answering System. Dataset includes 100k question and answer. (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YerevaNN/R-NET-in-Keras/master/data/dev-v1.1.json)
Original code from github:
https://github.com/YerevaNN/R-NET-in-Keras/blob/master/parse_data.py

I'm trying to implement this to similar dataset in Turkish.

Comment: `topic['paragraphs']` is integer not list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part `len(qa['answers'][0]['text'])` in your code throws the error because `len()` expects a string. You can verify yourself by typing `len(3)` in a python interpreter. Check your data whether the 'text' key in the array in qa['answers'] contains integer values somewhere. Or modify the piece of code if you actually want integers there.

I ran the portion from the original code and data you provided and it parsed w/o throwing errors. Since you mention you use a 'similar' dataset I assume you or someone else modified the contents...

(It would be helpful if you provided <strike>the original</strike> your dataset and your code)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Type error is true because of the poorly prepared data set. I found at that in json file, some parts are just wrong. For example, answer_start is expected to be a integer, but it has string values etc.

Comment: `len` expects not just a `str`, but any sized object (with `__len__` method implementation)